# Java: Reading .txt document and having access to the data

Tags: java, text, data-conversion

I have a .txt document with and list of names and information about them.
I want to read the .txt document and have access to the data, I then want to use the information in the data to workout averages, highest and lowest values.
Here is the info in the .txt document.

```
First Name, Surname, Age, Weight, Height
Tim, Simon, 37, 82, 178
barry, White, 21, 70, 176
Jason, Brink, 19, 67, 165
Caren, Dick, 22, 105, 200
Jackson, Michael, 81, 60, 170
Jerry, Springton, 6, 20, 111
```

I want to be able to calculate averages from this data.
Here is how I read out the data.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("/Users/Len/Desktop/TextReader/src/example.txt");

    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        while (input.hasNext()) {
        String num = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(num);
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.format("File Does Not Exist\n");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: @ModusTollens  I managed to read out the data. print it out line by line. But I am a Swift dev, How do I add this data to an array or dictionary to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to scan the individual values. For a simple implementation, you might use the [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class:

```
 String input = "Tim, Simon, 37, 82, 178";
 Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(", ");
 System.out.println(s.next());
 System.out.println(s.next());
 System.out.println(s.nextInt());
 System.out.println(s.nextInt());
 System.out.println(s.nextInt());
 s.close();
```

Next you will want to create a `Person` class to hold all the data for each person. See the [Java Tutorial on classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/index.html).

Next you will add each `Person` to a collection, such as an `ArrayList<Person>` for example:

```
List<Person> data = new ArrayList<>();
data.add(new Person(firstname, surname, age, weight, height));
```

Finally you will loop over the collection or use a stream to perform aggregate data computations.

Answer (score 0):

If you can read the data then I don't understand the problem in using it for calculation.

Suppose u read the above data in an arrays as -

```
fName[]
lName[]
age[]
widht[]
height[]
```

Then -

```
totHeight=0;
for(int height: height)
totHeight+=height;

avgheight=totHeight/totEntry;
```